# Maximum throughput of a corda application

Tags: blockchain, corda, throughput

I start working with corda plaform 3 days ago and currently i meet an issue about getting the thoughput of a corda application.

I worked with hyperledger before so the script i used for performance testing is caliper. The main idea is send transaction with send rate and see when the transaction is committed. With the information of time created and time committed i can calulate the throughput of the system. When i do the test for corda, i send transaction with send rate arround 50 txn per sec and get the thoughput of 3-5 tps.

The application i used for testing is cordapp-example with the default config. I configured to run with docker in my local machine (4 container - one for notary, 3 for node party).

So is that the actual performance of a corda application? Does anyone do this or have any article about this. I want to build a application with throughput arround 1000 tps. So what is the configuration for this system if using corda plaform (resources, number of nodes, etc,..)

Comment: May i ask how you configured nodes to run with docker ? Is there any documentation you have followed for this purpose ?

Comment: Checkout this link: https://docs.corda.r3.com/releases/3.1/sizing-and-performance.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source version of Corda isn't optimised and won't be able to reach 1000 tps. That's a pretty demanding use case. Try downloading the Enterprise version from here:

https://www.r3.com/corda-enterprise/

and see if you get better performance.

You might want also to email partner@r3.com and get a more formal relationship in place because we're constantly optimising to get higher and higher tps levels, so you'll probably want to be working closely with the performance team - in particular apps can do things that slow the node down and right now most of the knowledge about how to make fast apps is in the heads of the perf team. Over time there'll be optimisation advice added to the developer docs but we're not there yet.